# How to get google chrome bookmark in C# Code

Tags: c#

I have marked so many website as bookmark in google chrome.Is it possible to get content of bookmark (name,url etc) in C# Code.Actually my requirement is get bookmark from C# code and then export it in Excel file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome stores the bookmarks in the following file
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\bookmarks

This file is a JSON file so you can use a JSON parser like [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to open it and process the entries as you prefer.